# How to get Item from arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview

I have an arrayadapter named SmsArrayAdapter having the code as following :

```
public class SmsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    List<String> smsBody;
    List<Boolean> Status;
    Context context;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    String fromNumber;

    public SmsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> smsBody,List<Boolean> Status,
            String fromNumber) {
        super(context, resource, smsBody);
        this.smsBody = smsBody;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.fromNumber = fromNumber;
    }

    public String getStr(int position)
    {
        return smsBody.get(position);
    }

     @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return smsBody.get(position);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView textfrom;
        public TextView text_sms;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textfrom = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_from);
            holder.textfrom.setText(" SMS FROM " + fromNumber);
            holder.text_sms = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView_sms);
            String smsTextToDisplay = smsBody.get(position);
            if (smsTextToDisplay.length() > 100)
                smsTextToDisplay = smsTextToDisplay.substring(0, 99) + " ...";

            holder.text_sms.setText(smsTextToDisplay);

            if ( Status.get(position) == false ) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                        .getColor(R.color.light_blue_overlay));

            }

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();




        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I want to get the item of this arrayadapter . For this I have the following code :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

         String smsMessageStr = (String) arrayAdapter.getItem(pos);

         Toast.makeText(this, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

But I can not get the right item . What can I do ? How can I avoid this error ?

Comment: use `getItem(int position)` and remove `getStr`

Answer (score 1):

In adapter you can use getItem() to access items in list. Your array adapter holds string elements, getItem() returns a string object.

Comment: Try "String str = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);"